# OracleDB - Foreign Key constraint with dependencys

Tags: oracle, database-design

I know that this isn't the best design, but we have a database as it is and we have to adapt to it.
We have a Table "customizing":

`CREATE TABLE CUSTDATA
(
  TYPE NUMBER(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOT NULL 
, NUMBER NUMBER(5) 
, VALUE01 NUMBER(11)
, VALUE02 NUMBER(11) 
, TEXT01 VARCHAR2(50)
..
..
, CONSTRAINT CUSTDATA_PK PRIMARY KEY(
    TYPE,
    NUMBER));`

So, obviously the data is very dynamic
Type 1 can have 2 Numbers and different values
Type 5 can have 20 Numbers... 
The problem now is, that this is how the data is stored, in this table. And depending on the type it is clear what data to take from the values..

Now this is what we have

### What we want to do:

---

We want to set foreign keys from the new tables to this CUSTDATA Table. 
So Table XYZ Wants a Foreign Key on the CUSTDATA.NUMBER where TYPE = 3

How do we achieve that?
We tried it with views and constraint on views..
It just isn't beatiful, but how to handle a situation like this?

We will make Views on every type, just that you can see the Values that you need...

### Update:

maybe it wasn't that clear what we are trying to do. We dont want to transform the table into a new one. We want to use it with new types.

```html
create table xyz(
     doesntmatterkey        NUMBER(11)
    ,foreignNR
    ,CONSTRAINT xyz_PL PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    doesntmatterkey 
  )
, CONSTRAINT ADRPOSTALADR_FK1 FOREIGN KEY
    (
    foreignNR
      )
    REFERENCES CUSTDATA
    (
      TYPE = 3000
      NUMBER <- this is the real foreign column
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in other databases by adding a new generated column:

```
create table xyz (
    . . . ,
    custdata_number number(5),
    custdata_type generated always as (3),
    constaint fk_xyz_custdata_number_type (custdata_type, custdata_number) references custdata(type, number)
);
```

Comment: please note the update, now i think it is more clear what we are trying to achieve... sorry for the bad english